# how to retrieve data from firebase to change variable in java

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I make an apps to teach children with autism to learn communication. This app is for limited user, so the user needs register to admin for use the application.

The user sends their bio-data such as name, institution, and "disetujui" to the firebase database.

The app sends information with "disetujui" default value is 0.

After an admin accepts the data, admin set value "disetujui" to 1, that make user can login to the app.

Now for the login in the app, I can't make the app know the value is already change to 1, after I retrieve the data, value "disetujuiDb" in app is still 0.

How I can retrieve "disetujui" and use it in different method?

Interface:

```java
    public interface LoginInterface<T> {
    void callback(T data);
}
```

Model:

```java
class Tablet(val deviceId: String,
        val namaPenanggungJawab: String,
        val namaInstitusi: String,
        val noTelpYangDapatDihubungi: String,
        val email :String,
        val Disetujui: Int)
```

Login code:

```java
int disetujuiDb = 0;

private void disetujuiDb(@NonNull final LoginInterface<Boolean> finishedCallback){
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds") final String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        databaseReference.child("Tablet").child(deviceId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                finishedCallback.callback(dataSnapshot.child("disetujui").getValue().equals(1));
                Log.i("value_callback", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("disetujui").getValue()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isValid() {
        String message = null;
        disetujuiDb(new LoginInterface<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void callback(Boolean data) {
                if (data) {
                    disetujuiDb = 1;

                }
            }
        });

        Log.i("value_disetujuidb",disetujuiDb+"");

        if (etUsername.getText().toString().equals(""))
            message = getString(R.string.username) + " belum diisi";
        else if (etPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
            message = getString(R.string.password) + " belum diisi";
        else if (disetujuiDb == 0){
            message = "Tablet Belum Didaftarkan atau Menunggu dari Admin MIKA untuk di Konfirmasi";
        }


        if (message != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return message == null;
    }
```

Here the data in firebase:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPrpU.png)

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the disetujuiDb function?

Comment: in isValid() methode

Comment: I think the problem is you are missing a child in accessing the value. In the provided photo there is a `tablet` node, then a `key` node( *you scratched it with blue color* ) and then the `deviceId` node ( `tablet` -> `key` -> `deviceId` ). and in your code your acessing as `tablet` -> `deviceId`. You are missing the `key` child node in your code

Comment: I set The key for firebase is "deviceId", i scratched it with blue color just for privacy, so the scratched with blue color are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your finishedcallback to be

> finishedCallback.callback(dataSnapshot.child("disetujui").getValue().toString().equals("1"));

I tried your code .equals(1) return false

Then its because the call is async and your condition (if-else) is on main thread, so the condition checks while the call still on going and might not return the data yet.

Try to move the condition after the callback is called

```
disetujuiDb(new LoginInterface<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public void callback(Boolean data) {
            if (data) {
                disetujuiDb = 1;
            }

            Log.i("value_disetujui", disetujuiDb + ""); // the value should be 1 now

            if (etUsername.getText().toString().equals(""))
                message = getString(R.string.username) + " belum diisi";
            else if (etPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
                message = getString(R.string.password) + " belum diisi";
            else if (disetujuiDb == 0){
                message = "Tablet Belum Didaftarkan atau Menunggu dari Admin MIKA untuk di Konfirmasi";
            }
            if (message != null) {
               Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps you